# Symfony redirects - routers.yaml before annotations.yaml

Tags: symfony, redirect, routes

I'm using annotations in my project but to redirects using routes.yaml
If exists routing (ex. /home name="home"} that redirect not working:

```
home-301:
    path: /home
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /new-home
        permanent: true
```

I found solution but I thing it is no good practice:

cleared: config/routes/annotations.yaml
and appended to the end of the file config/routes.yaml:

```
controllers:
  resource: ../../src/Controller/
  type: annotation
```

how to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

all redirects put in: config/routers/redirects.yaml

**and config/routes.yaml:**

```
redirects:
  resource: routes/redirects.yaml

annotations:
  resource: routes/annotations.yaml
```